Should I have 12V on coil ign off
Should I have 12V on the coil with the igntion OFF?  Common sense tells me no.  So, why do I?  Cuz I  do ?

What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

1969 Mercury Cougar 351 V8

Basically, loud backfire, engine stalled.   Now I have no spark from dist to plugs.

Ignition switch off, coil power off. Ignition switch on, coil power is cycled on and off thru the distributor points. Points closed, sends 12v to primary coil windings. Points opening  disables power to primary coil, the collapsing magnetic field generating high voltage from the secondary windings sending high voltage thru the rotor, cap and spark plug wire to spark plug. When correctly timed, spark occurs at top dead center of each cylinder. Check distributor point gap, possible condenser failure and distributor timing.
